# Java Tcp client message comparison

Tags: java, tcp

I am trying to write a TCP server to compare message's from more than one client
How do I compare multi client's message?

Example: A client send 3.00
B client send 4.00
I will return B won to clients

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets) website. You can use websocket.